# DOM is not reflecting changes eventho the variable has the new value

Tags: vuejs3

I have a vue Modal Component which has a file input field where I upload images to a firestore storage:

```
<script setup>
import { defineProps, defineEmits, ref, reactive } from 'vue'
import { useFirebaseUpload } from '@/use/useFirebaseUpload'

const podcastData = reactive({
  title: '',
  content: '',
  category: '',
  image: ''
})

const { file, progress } = useFirebaseUpload((url) => {
  // Update the image property in podcastData when the downloadUrl is available
  podcastData.image = url
  // the podcastData.image variable receives correctly the new uploaded image
  console.log('from ModalComponent', podcastData.image)
})

const emit = defineEmits(['update:modelValue', 'addPodcast'])

const handleFileChange = (event) => {
  file.value = event.target.files[0]
}
</script>
```

The procedure to upload the image is done with a  composable `useFirebaseUpload.js`:

```js
export function useFirebaseUpload(setUrl) {
  const file = ref(null)
  const uploadTask = ref(null)
  const imageUrl = ref('')
  const progress = ref(0)

  // Watch for file changes
  watch(file, async (newFile) => {
    if (!newFile) return

    const fileRef = firebaseRef(storage, `images/${file.value.name}`)
    uploadTask.value = uploadBytesResumable(fileRef, newFile)

    // Handle state changes and progress
    uploadTask.value.on(
      'state_change',
      (snapshot) => {
        // Progress updates
        progress.value = (snapshot.bytesTransferred / snapshot.totalBytes) * 100
      },
      (error) => {
        console.error(error)
      },
      async () => {
        try {
          // Get download URL on completion
          imageUrl.value = await getDownloadURL(fileRef)
          console.log('from useFirebaseUpload.js', imageUrl.value)
          setUrl(imageUrl.value) // Call the callback function
        } catch (error) {
          console.error('Error getting download URL:', error)
        }
      }
    )
  })

  return { file, imageUrl, progress }
}
```

When the upload process is done, the callback function
`setUrl(imageUrl.value)`
sets the value of `podcastData.image` variable to reflect the new uploaded image when editing the podcast post.
The issue is, even though `podcastData.image` has the new value, the DOM doesn't update itself with the new image to show.

```js
const podcastData = reactive({
  title: '',
  content: '',
  category: '',
  image: ''
})
```

This behavior happens only on Editing podcast Posts, and not when Creating a new podcast Post.
I can't find the issue because, as I say, everything works and the `podcastData.image` variable is updated correctly with the new image path.

Comment: In its current form, your issue is not reproducible, which means we can't test any potential solution, bringing your chances of getting a useful answer very close to zero. Consider creating a *runnable* [mcve] using codesandbox.io or similar.

Comment: It's unclear why you're passing a `setUrl` function to the hook, instead of returning a promise from it and setting the url in the consumer component, when the promise resolves. Again, without a *runnable* example, you're making quite difficult for anyone to help you.

Comment: @tao, I found the issue, it was because i was using ```podcastData.image``` declared as a reactive object, and that wasnt allowing to update in realitme the image when its value changed. I set it again to be a ref value and now it works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`podcastData.image` was declared as a reactive() object, and that wasnt allowing to update the image value in realitme when its value changed. I set it again to be a ref() value and now it works